# Where is the python path set when I don't have a .bash_profile?

Tags: python

I am running ubuntu, and I don't have a .bash_profile.

So my question is, where exactly is my python path set then?

How can I see what the current python path is, doing:

```
$PYTHON_PATH
```

doesn't return anything?

Comment: it's PYTHONPATH and not PYTHON_PATH, as others mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's set by the `site` module, and the interpreter executable itself. `sys.path` contains the current value.

Answer (score 4):

You can see your python path in python like so:

```
>> import sys
>> print sys.path
```

Comment: sys.path lists a long list of paths. However, if I exit the python shell and type `echo $PYTHONPATH`, I get nothing. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @shailenTJ If you are using virtualenv (add2virtualenv) PYTHONPATH will show nothing for you (empty return). All paths added by virtualenv (add2virtualenv command) are saved inside /path/to/your/site-packages/_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth

Answer (score 1):

you can create a .bash_profile with your favorite editor, and put into it:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/python
```

or whatever, that's one example.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $PYTHONPATH`  /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc are the global setting files bash scans before looking in your home directory at start up.  It's also safe to create a .bash_profile if one doesn't exist.

Normally PYTHONPATH is empty anyways.

Comment: Normally PYTHONPATH is not set and it's different from empty: empty PYTHONPATH is the same as setting it to CWD.